# Empty XML when variable used in TSQL stored procedure called by Script Task in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a SSIS package using a Script Task to output a xml file from a SQL task. The SQL task calls a stored procedure. The stored procedure creates the xml output result and inserts into a ssis variable so the scripts task can create the actual xml file. All this works fine as long as the stored procedure does not use a (internal) variable with xml datatype.

In other words if you code the stored procedure like this it works fine:

```
SELECT ABC
FROM Table
FOR XML PATH etc.
```

But if you use a variable inside the stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @X1 XML
SET @X1 = 
(SELECT ABC 
 FROM TABLE
 FOR XLM PATH etc )
SELECT @X1
```

Then the script task gives an SSIS error:

> MSSQLError HResult="0x80004005" Source="Microsoft XML Extensions to SQL Server" Description="No description provided"?>

**What can I do to prevent this error?**

Running the code in SSMS works fine, but it seems the Script Task doesn't handle the variable inside the SP very well even though the datatype never changed (compared to not using the variable inside SP).

The SSIS variable is String type (As far as I know there is no xml type in ssis). The script is in MS Visual C# 2008, partial code looks like this:

```
//string Data = Dts.Variables["XMLcode"].Value.ToString();
  string Data = Dts.Variables["XMLcode"].Value.ToString().Replace("<ROOT>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>").Replace("</ROOT>", "");
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(Data.ToString());
            string outputFile = Dts.Variables["FilePath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value.ToString();
            xdoc.Save(outputFile);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

The reason I am using a xml dataype variable in the SP is that I have to use xml.modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using ADO.net connection?  In order to return an XML result only the ADO.NET Connection Manager has to be used.

. In ADO.NET you need to pass the parameter as @para instead of ?

Comment: Aha, I used OLEDB, but now it works. I found my own solution actually, that is by converting the variable in the stored procedure to a NVARCHAR(MAX).